# iterating number type in express-edge?

Tags: express

isn't it possible to itereate through a `number` type variable in express-edge? On their official docs they mentioned iteration of objects and arrays and when I tried to iterate a `number` type variable it didn't worked (i mean like a simple loop, will run for `n` times)

so basically i'm trying to impelment a pagination, my controller for this look something like this:

```js
// get total documents in the Posts collection
    const count = await Posts.countDocuments();
    const tpgs = Math.ceil(count / limit);

    // return response with posts, total pages, and current page
    res.render("index",{
      psts: posts,
      totalPages: tpgs,
      currentPage: page
    });
```

and the html (with express-edge) looks something like this:

```html
@if(totalPages > 0)
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination">

            @each(p in totalPages)

              @if(p == 1)
              <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
              </li>
              @else
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="posts/{{ p - 1}}">Previous</a></li>
              @endif

              @if(p == currentPage)
                <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                  <a class="page-link" href="{{ p }}">{{ p }}</a>
                </li>
              @else
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="posts/{{ p }}">{{ p }}</a></li>
              @endif

              @if(p == totalPages)
              <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="posts/{{ p + 1}}">Next</a>
              </li>
              @else
              <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="posts/{{ p + 1}}">Next</a>
              </li>
              @endif

            @endeach

          </ul>
        </nav>
        @endif
```

Comment: What are you iterating N times?  Why don't you show the input data and then show the desired output HTML for your loop and then folks can offer ideas for how to create a template that does that.  Theoretical questions are hard to answer here because they are so non-specific.  Precise questions that show your data and your desired result have a much better chance of attracting an answer.

Comment: added relevent codes